# How to install flash player for firefox on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, flash

I have tried to follow the steps recommended in https://linuxconfig.org/enable-adobe-flash-for-firefox-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

But when I enter **sudo apt install flashplugin-installer** into my shell, it tells me **the package flushplugin-installer could not be found**.

REMARK: I know flash is an old software virtually no one uses anymore, but I need it in order to view content embedded in newspaper articles that were published ten years ago.

Comment: Does Firefox still allow Flash? It was always a fruitful source of bugs.

Comment: set up a VM running an ancient version of Ubuntu or something, install firefox & flash on that.

Comment: This blog has some useful information on how to proceed: https://www.howtogeek.com/707830/how-to-use-adobe-flash-in-2021-and-beyond/ . Ruffle - an open-source Flash emulator - is a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended installing Flash player after EOL.

[Adobe Flash Player EOL General Information Page](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html)

> Since Adobe no longer supports Flash Player after December 31, 2020 and blocked Flash content from running in Flash Player beginning January 12, 2021, Adobe strongly recommends all users immediately uninstall Flash Player to help protect their systems.

If I found flash player available for download on a third-party website, should I use it?

> You should not use unauthorized versions of Flash Player.  Unauthorized downloads are a common source of malware and viruses.

Comment: +1 For not installing `any` software that's EOL as it's no longer receiving security updates. That's one of the best ways to avoid malware.